# Shantungosaurus chase, mad max style

Tags: alternate-worlds, travel, dinosaurs

I have a scene where there's a [Shantungosaurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shantungosaurus#:%7E:text=Shantungosaurus%20giganteus%20is%20one%20of,(48%20ft)%20in%20length.) chase in [Mad Max](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mad_Max) style, except there's no such thing as motor technology and the closest thing to guns are portable repeating [polybolos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polybolos) (scoprion balistae but mounted to the sides of the dinosaur)

**What happened:**

The main character of this scene, let's call her Arobase it's an alien like individual in the mind , hard to decipher, social and even heroic in certain situations but straight out homicidal with the ability to kill innocents without a second thought, doesn't speak but communicates through her own hand sign language that only her friend knows, hence why Arobase drags her friend arround, to communicate with others while traveling. Arobase is quite sadistic, which makes her into a fierce warrior that has  never lost a single fight yet, but I need her to get injured severly to make her learn the importance of teamwork, after this injury she will start paying for escorts/mercenaries to protect her flanks. The injury happens after Arobase and her friend buy a Shantungosaurus to travel around by land and then get's chased down by ''land pirates'' or bandits riding another Shantungosaurus. The fight is 1 versus 4, since Arobase will jump on the pirate  Shantungosaurus to leave her friend a chance to escape while she distracts them, she manages to kill two of them, capture one of them which she will sell as a slave and the last one will fall off the ride and be left behind, apparently the dinosaur could only run at an estimate of 36 kilometers per hour, which is survivable from a height of 5 meters, maybe with one or two small composed fractures. Either way I need the two bandits/pirates to survive.

The reason Arobase decided to travel by land was because she is afraid of the ocean, it's not like a phobia where she can't touch water, and she can swim pretty well but this isn't enough for her to consider the idea of traveling by sea ever desiderable.

**Question**

I need a reason for why people would sell shantungosaurus as rides in the first place, they are heavy, bulky and probably eat a lot of food and those are only the most obvious drawbacks, the list can be way longer.

**Details**

- [This is my wolrd map](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/221330/in-a-supercontinent-would-ships-still-be-the-primary-way-of-transportation-befor)
- The world is filled with dangers both inside the water and on land
- Arobase is not from this world, while she was writing an exam she blinked and reopened her eyes to find herself naked on top of a clif surrounded by a forest, it's been 2 years since she was transported in this new world.

Comment: For those who don't know, *[arobase](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arobase)* is the French word for the @ sign. (Or rather, **a** French word. The traditional name of the @ sign is *a commercial*, from the time when it was used in phrases like "5 kilos of sugar @ 4 francs the kilo".)

Comment: New rule: Every story from now on requires at least one dinosaur chase scene. 

Comment: @AlexP oh I thoght Arobase was the international name, thanks for the clarification

Comment: The question has loads of irrelevant details. It would be enough to write "My world has many dangers in the wilderness. In particular there are dinosaurs. My story has a chase scene between two Shantungosaurus. Why would people use these dinosaurs as mounts when they obviously take up a lot of space and cost a lot to feed?"

Comment: Also some details like technology level, distance of travel, and terrain types make a big difference. I guess you want pre-industrial technology and big swathes of wild jungle between the cities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Shantungosaurus is really, really big.**

[image: shants]

Q:/I need a reason for why people would sell shantungosaurus as rides in the first place/

A:  /The world is filled with dangers both inside the water and on land/

Shants are the equivalent of elephants.  They are formidable.  There are not many things on water or land that will mess with a grown elephant or shantungosaurus.  Many things (especially crocodilians and predatory amphibians) that would be happy to attack a human or a human on a lesser mount will stay well away from a shantungosaurus.  It is like riding an elephant through tiger country except these dinosaurs are much bigger than elephants.

Another good thing about shantungosaurus is that they are fine in the water.  The swampy country your characters are traversing has places where the water is several meters deep.  That is fine for the shants and they can even swim a little if they see something solid ahead of them.

Also in the lush lowlands where people use shantungosaurus, the creatures can feed themselves as they move.  They eat a wide variety of plants and can grab and munch as they walk.  That saves on cost.  They are not averse to some carrion if they can get it.

Make sure your character keeps the pirate shantungosauruses.  Or better - they come with on their own because they like to be in groups.  She can sell all of them at the far side of the swamplands.  Your pirate guy does not want to be left alone out there and he is happy to come with too - he can cook and so feels pretty confident about being sold as a slave.

His cooking is also appreciated en route.   Maybe Arobase and her friend decide to keep him.

Answer (score 1):

Q: *"The injury happens after Arobase and her friend buy a Shantungosaurus to travel around by land and then get's chased down by ''land pirates'' or bandits riding another Shantungosaurus"*

Q: *"I need a reason for why people would sell shantungosaurus as rides in the first place, they are heavy, bulky and probably eat a lot of food and those are only the most obvious drawbacks, the list can be way longer."*

**The elite rides them**

Don't worry about the cost, Arobase's transformer will take care of that. These sauruses are not cheap: only the elite rides Shantungosauruses. There are no horses.. Shantungosaurus are the horses of your world, and it's a rich knight's hobby to maintain them and feed them. You'll pay a fortune, but the animal is worth it. They are smart, they can easily be kept. Only trouble is, the pirates raised their own, they know far better than Arobase how to handle them. That's why she gets into trouble. She bought one.. but  unfortunately, the seller is not really interested in what happens after the sale. Why they do it ? It is just Shantungosaurus-selling business. There's demand..