# How to monetize soap bubble portals that travel across dimensions and bring various creatures and objects from different times/places in one planet

Tags: science-fiction, economy, money, portal

In my project there's a species of creatures capable of bending reality, using very advanced technology they achieved the power to travel through dimensions using portals.

The portals work like soap bubbles, air can't pass and even liquids cannot pass... but a solid can enter the bubble without popping it.

**fun expertiment: try pushing your finger or a needle inside a soap bubble, if you are slow enough you might be able to get inside without popping it**

In my story an incident happened that caused bubble portals to appear for a very brief moment, less than second on earth as well as on other planets, all connected to another world. Since those bubbles can defy not only space but also time ; in a fraction of a second creatures on earth from diffent time periods where transported to this other world but at different intervals.

Details:

-The incident happened on day 1

-People from ancient rome and people from the modern era as an example  where transported on day 1 of the incident on world X at different years. the incident happened only once but people where transported at different speeds thus some arrived days later than others, some may even arrive millenia later.

-Not just people were transported but anything the bubble took with it.

-The bubble portals do not work like teletrapostation, but like windows to other worlds, moments and realities.

-World X belongs to a new universe that was instantly created by the incident, in this universe 7 billion years passed instantly creating planets and galaxies and all that can inhabit an universe in a span of time equal to zero. In short 7 billion years happened in 0 seconds.

-The bubbles take everything inside of them, which means that some people may leave pieces of their bodies behind if they are unlucky enough to get on the edge of the bubble

This is a visual representation of what I'm talking about, by Vladyslav Horobets.
[image]

**Question**

Someone managed to figure out when and where the next and last 5 portals will arrive on world X.
How can they monetize this knowledge? They don't know what will the bubble portals bring with them, they only know when they will happen and where. The goal is for the inidividual to make enough money to finance their own private army of 50k soldiers which need training, shelter, food and equipment.

**Is this question story and opinion based ?**

I have an endgoal, an origin, I have the tools to get from start to finish.
I just need a realistic monetization method, which should be good enough for this website as it fits the tag ''economy''

This is the world.
[image]

The person who needs to monetize the bubble portals is located in [Velsia](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/221330/in-a-supercontinent-would-ships-still-be-the-primary-way-of-transportation-befor), a nation divided in smaller states, similar to ancient Greece in it's role as a trade center.
The technology level on most of the planet is very primitive, but since some people and items were transported from different ages it can change from place to place. There are empires, countries, factions, guilds and federations in the world... various cultures with various political systems and beliefs.

Before someone asks:

There are also various ''sapient'' species which I won't bother making a list now since the list will grow and grow continuosly as I will be adding new stuff and I'm already at 135 different sapient species, this is a learning project and Everything that I can think of I will model and animate to learn as much as possible. Also, this is a multi-dimension-multi-time concept, perfect chance to make any possible creature into a real thing. So just pretend that everyone is human, then I will adapt your suggestions and answers as I add new stuff to the world.

Comment: [If you are looking for an easy to follow step-by-step for your bubbles I suggest this one.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tn5ywPFetAY)

Comment: We can't tell you how to monetize some technology because everyone will have a different opinion. Please include specific uses which you consider for your plot and participants can possibly guide you on their economic possibilities.

Answer (score 5):

**Bidders.**

1. Obtain title to properties where bubbles will appear.  Quietly!
2. Loads of PR about how awesome the stuff is that appears in bubbles!  Bored rich people must have a bubble!
3. Rights to contents of each bubble (give swanky names - the Vermillon Bubble!  Bulle Jaune!) are sold to highest bidder in very public auction.
4. Sell all before any appear because if one appears full of dirt and earwigs, bids for subsequent will not be high.
5. Use FABULOUS PROCEEDS to trick out and feed private army.

Comment: Step 4.5: Disappear, in case the bubbles bring something worthless or lethal.

Answer (score 3):

There are three groups of people to focus on for this person to get the money they want: the government, scientists, and rich fanatics who are crazy enough to part with their money.

The governments of the world obviously have a vested interest in knowing when and where portals are going to show up on their land, so all this person has to do is convince the governments that they know exactly where the portals will line up, but promise to only tell them if they offer a hefty sum of money in return. That's the first step, convincing the governments that this is a matter of national urgency. The person running this operation should definitely make sure to have the deal in writing beforehand too, to make sure they do in fact get the money.

Have this person make friends with scientists too. Obviously, otherworldly portals are going to offer all sorts of hefty scientific discoveries, so people interested in advancing human technology are going to be drooling to figure out what kinds of new things they will uncover. Have this person make a deal with them as well but with two stipulations.

One, any scientists that want to study this have to pay a certain amount to learn the secret location.

Two, they want a cut of the profit if any new technologies come about from studying these portals. For example, if the scientists use the portals to make new teleportation technology, they had better hand over a cut of the profit. If an alien organism pops out, and they study it to find a cure to all known diseases, the person who told them where the portal was in the first place wants a cut of the profit for sure.

Also, if I was this person, I'd also use this information to get as many rich nutjobs on my side as physically possible. If they own a wealthy corporation and want to send a probe or a live person into the portal to study what happens, you'd better believe I would ask them to pay me first, with a contract saying I am not liable to anything that happens should the probe not return or the portal ends up unstable.

You could also try using this information to paint yourself as something of a prophet. You could try to play up this alternate dimension as a sort of paradise. Going through it means ascension from this mortal plane. You don't even necessarily have to lie, just say stuff like "your life will never be the same" and "you'll be one with the universe".

There are so many people, rich or otherwise, who would devour that nonsense like hungry dogs. Convince them that this is a portal to paradise, and they'd pay you through the nose just to jump through that portal, even if it meant certain death. It's only a matter of finding people crazy enough to do so and making them sign a waiver beforehand. There are enough gullible people in the world that this should be relatively easy.

Heck, I'm sure people would pay just to be near the portal when it shows up, as it would be an experience unlike any other. Just sell tickets and block off the area so only people who paid the proper price are allowed to see. It might be safest to view the portals through a camera, but if there are people crazy enough to want to watch it directly, they have to pay extra. If they want to go through the portal, they have to pay a lot more.

You should be able to make a lot of money, enough to pay for a small squad of elite fighters.

Of course, this is provided that you don't get betrayed, like the government folks just don't bother paying you, or the rich folks decide you're scamming them and throw you into the portal rather than asking for a refund.

Answer (score 2):

**Some rich escapists prepared to loose a limb ?**

Issue 1 - safety

*"The bubbles take everything inside of them, which means that some people may leave pieces of their bodies behind"*

If that is the case, you'll have an issue in the amusement industry! safety *must* be guaranteed, else you won't get a permit, or get sued for damages.. or get killed by their friends.. depending on the level of civilization.

Issue 2 - returning home

Also, it would be nice for your space time tourists, to have a way to return home. Do these bubbles provide for a return ticket, else the only scenario I can think of is providing criminals or prisoners means of escape. Maybe some rich escapist would consider taking a ride ?

Comment: The question seems to suggest that the bubbles are a one-way trip.

Comment: Better regard this as a frame challenge.. I don't think this adventure will yield a lot of money, unless you have a "customer" attempting an escape in space time :d :d

Answer (score 1):

### Assumptions

There's a lot of text, so let me preface some understandings before putting an answer:

- The person doing the monetizing is on World X (the target world)
- The person doing the monetizing knows only where and when the next five bubbles in $X_{t,x,y,z}^{t=n..n+5}$ are going to appear on World X.

  - in time, latitude, longitude, and altitude
- These bubbles are the same Day One bubbles that brought everyone else to World X

### Ways to Monetize This Knowledge

##### The Intrinsic Value of the Cargo

Assuming we're some distance in time from the first bubbles landing on World X. There are probably books written by passengers attempting to catalog the events.

A sage might be able to notice trends in this data. Not that the system is deterministic, but that, for example, 100% of the time what came through was physical - never a liquid or a gas. Maybe also, 100% of the time, the thing that passes into the bubble does so from the outside; does so slowly (so as not to pop the bubble). This would, I think, likely also mean that 90+% of the time what passes through a bubble is at least intelligent enough to be curious, and drawn into the bubble by curiosity. Maybe even 60-80% of the time, this is a human being (animals usually being frightened off by the things). And the humans, maybe, are often (95%) curious civilians unprepared for what happens to them.

There might also be a trend as to where/when $O_{t,x,y,z}$ from the Origin World appear. Let's call our monetizer Joe. World X has evolved with this hodge-podge of Day One stuff scattered in the past, but there exists some average tech "age" for our buddy Joe. Maybe it's just dumb luck, but 65% of the bubbles come from an $O_t$ that is still in Joe's "future".

Joe would know a few things with some certainty

- There's almost surely people coming through the bubble
- They are very likely from his "relative" future
- Regardless of how futuristic they are, the people are likely defenseless

Joe could send agents to collect these people. He could be nice, or cruel; but the point of these trusted agents is to pump the new arrivals for whatever they know, trade for anything Joe finds really cool that the New Arrivals would be happy to part with, and bring these novelties to market. Maybe even hire a craftsman (if he'd be so lucky) from the New Arrivals, to spare him the R+D cost.

##### The Value of the Portals

However, if the cargo's value is completely unknowable (or the likelihood is highest that the bubble is empty of valuable contents), the portals may have some value in themselves.

Here's some possibilities --

- The descendants of $O_{t,x,y,z}$ may have theorized a way to get "home" to the Origin World. You could see that the "windows" do sound like they might go both ways. The theory may not be true. But, these nations might be willing to pay handsomely for that precious information where the next $X_{t,x,y,z,}$ bubbles are appearing, so that they can try.
- World X was created and billions of years of matured in seconds. The most technologically advanced culture on World X might want to pay a fortune for a chance to study a bubble. There are obvious breakthroughs that might be learned here in : time travel, teleportation, energy, creating universes.
- Someone (maybe Joe) thinks he's cracked how to use the bubbles to get to another time+place on World X (maybe he wants to go to his own past and right a wrong), or Origin World.
- Someone (maybe Joe) think he (or she) have cracked how to create a custom universe, and intend to use a bubble to leave World X and become a god on New World Y

##### Fraud

Maybe the most profitable, is the least honest use of the information. Our monetizer Joe may suspect nothing valuable is coming through the bubble, and he has no way to make use of the bubble in it's own right.

Joe can advertise that he's found a way back to Origin World, or the future+past of World X, or New World Y. It's not true, but nobody knows that.

If Joe can prove he knows where the first bubble was, people will tend to believe the second part of the story (the lie). Joe can extract almost any fee he wants selling the location of bubbles 2 through 5.